# Pre-/suffixing a Source stream in Play 2.5

Tags: json, scala, playframework, streaming, akka

Lets say I have a Play Controller with this method -

```
def persons(): Action[AnyContent] =
  Action { _ =>
    Ok.chunked(personSource.map { p => JsObject(p) }
  )
}
```

The Akka Source stream is a large but finite stream of Persons from, say our db. Loading all of it into memory at once would lead to out of memory exceptions.

The code above works fine, I get a long stream of json objects:

```
{"name": "TestPerson1}{"name": "TestPerson2"}
```

But now a client has requested the response has this format:

```
[{"name": "TestPerson1},{"name": "TestPerson2"}]
```

I am having troubles finding how to emit prefix/suffix to the stream. Maybe a filter, or nesting Actions? But the examples I find of that tend to operate on the Request such as redirecting, or having side-effecting operations such as logging something before handing over processing to the inner Action.

I would like to emit "[" at the start of the http response, keep the Source async chunked processing in the middle, and then emit a "]" at the end.

Comment: You can easily concat sources of chunks

Comment: @cchantep Ah right I can do it on stream Source level if I map the Person source to a Source[String], and then use Source.concat(next). Thanks I will post a full solution if I get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Solution found thanks to @cchantep

```
val persons = source.map { p => JsObject(p).toString }.intersperse(",")
Action { _ =>
  Ok.chunked(Source(List("[")).concat(persons).concat(Source(List("]"))))
}
```

Or even simpler (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125603/akka-stream-how-to-treat-the-last-element-of-a-stream-differently-in-a-flow-gr) page, which I didn't find before):

```
Ok.chunked(source.map { p => JsObject(p).toString }.intersperse("[", ",", "]") )
```